# After getting a deleted partition with Testdisk software, can I recover it on the unallocated space of the deleted partition without any problem?

Tags: data-recovery

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my PC. My linux partition was accedentaly deleted. So, I'm trying to recover deleted partition with Testdisk, and I'm using Ubuntu Live CD since my Linux  partition is deleted. I have found my files with the software, but where should I recover them. Can I recover them on the deleted partition(the unallocated space which was linux previously) without any problem of overwriting and permanent data loss?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will just restore the partition record. No data from the Windows partition will be lost, the Linux data won't be touched too.

EDIT: After deleting and recovering partitions from an old drive, here's the result (F:, shared, has music in it, restored and G: made by mistake before deleting F:)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, but another problem I'm facing is, before I click 'write' button for recovery, must all partitions be displayed(on the list of partitions, above the buttons 'quit' 'deeper search' and 'write') or is it only the deleted partition that  should be displayed?

Comment: Well, for me, it shows all partitions (incl. the deleted one).

Comment: Are you sure of my 1st question, because another post below says a different thing.

Comment: Yes, I am, I've restored a partition. I'll do it on an old hard drive right now.

Comment: @Kirubel, look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately we can't store recovered files on the same partition of a drive. As soon as we start writing on that partition all file-remnants that still reside there will be overwritten with the new data, hence **making them irreversibly unrecoverable**.

In case there is another partition **different** to the space we want to recover we may successfully harvest our files to there, but still **we can not restore the partition table**, as this affects the whole drive's partitioning.

To be on the safe side it is recommended to harvest recovered files on another, possibly external drive.